# How to insert "Dynamic Content" in uib-accordion developed with ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-accordion

I have created an uib-accordion in my angular project, where all the uib-accordion-group elements have been created under ng-repeat(for efficiency ofcourse).

```
<uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
    <ul ng-model="some_code">
        <li ng-repeat="some_code">
            <div uib-accordion-group heading="{{some_code}}">
                {{some_code}}
            </div>
        </li>
   </ul>
</uib-accordion>
```

The problem is I want to insert **different** and **dynamic content** in the `uib-accordion-group(s)` but being in ng-repeat I can't use `template-url`. I have almost 6 rows to be displayed. Should I fall back to developing each accordion row individually(*which would increase code size, hence I don't want*) or do we have any such provision in uib-accordion (*which maybe I am currently not aware of*)?

Suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

try to use ng-class and change the styles dynamically

Comment: [Comments posted as an answer are subject to removal.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Answer (score -1):

The html code you want to put in each accordion. Are you getting it dynamically or you have the code you just want to put different code on different condition.

Comment: The page receives the data from back-end. Depending on the no. of data fields, which is a function of time, the html page, which is basically a form, changes.

Comment: What i understand you are getting a Array of object and in every object you are getting some fields according to which you want to create form elements.

Comment: Thanks for responding guys. Unfortunately, I have not been able to figure out the solution yet.

Can anyone tell me one more thing please : I am trying to pass the value of template-url from the controller by conventional angular binding, but it is not working. It works fine if I directly type the file path inside template-url directive. Why is it happening so ?